# How to send azure push notification by portal to Android?

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am new to azure, so i just started with sending push notification by portal, i did below steps and i got fail to get notification in android device while i got success notification with Outtcome:{0 passed, 0 failed) like below picture.

[image]

i made a blank android app and by which i got server key that is perfectly working because i test it by http://pushtry.com/

how can i solve my problem please can anyone help me....

Comment: Have you tried going through [Sending push notifications to Android with Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started)? Once you go through the tutorial, try the test send from the portal, it should work.

Comment: @ Nikita G thanks i try it.. (y)

Comment: @Nikita G, I have a blank app, so in that link a point is there(Connect your app to the notification hub) after connecting with GCM, so should my blank app follow that steps to Connect your app to the notification hub ? or is it fine without it ?

Comment: i mean i have already a blank app and i want to send push notification by that blank app so can i do it with that or i have to make a new blank app which should be configured with azure notification hub as shown in that link point(Connect your app to the notification hub)  ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should follow that steps to connect your app to the notification hub.

Currently, Google is migrating from the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) platform to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).

- So, first of all, you need to create a new project from [Google's Firebase   Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).
- Then add Firebase to your Android app, you can follow the steps in [this guide](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android-push-notifications).
- Then [configure a new notification hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started#configure-a-new-notification-hub).
- Finally, [connect your app to the notification hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started#a-idconnecting-appaconnect-your-app-to-the-notification-hub).

At this point, you can send push notifications to Android app with the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com).

Comment: without this final step  connect your app to the notification hub. can i not send push  notification ?

Comment: i have blank app without connected to the notification hub so can i not able to send push notification ?

Comment: are you there ? please help me

Comment: Per my experience, you are NOT able to send push notifications to the blank app without connected to the notification hub.

Comment: @ Aaron Chen - MSFT my blank app means a complete app without connected to the notification hub, are also getting it or taking in a wrong way ?

Comment: We need to connect our app to notification hub for registration, which is a required step.