# Azure: Should a blank android app configure with azure library to send azure push notification or not?

Tags: android, azure, push-notification, notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am new to azure and firstly i want to send push notification by azure portal, so i was reading this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started

i have already a blank android app and i want to send push notification by that blank app so can i do it with that or i have to make a new blank app which should be configured with azure notification hub as described in above links point(Connect your app to the notification hub)  after connecting with FCM ?

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It IS possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started#optional-send-push-notifications-directly-from-the-app), but **NOT recommended** as your referenced documentation said as below.

> This example of sending notifications from the client app is provided for learning purposes only. Since this will require the DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature to be present on the client app, it exposes your notification hub to the risk that a user may gain access to send unauthorized notifications to your clients.

If you are making your app for public purpose, bad user could get security key of push notification and could send spam messages. So, to address this issue, you need to create Azure WebApp to register and send push message.

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534422/how-to-send-azure-push-notification-by-portal-to-android?noredirect=1#comment72210740_42534422  i am in problem please help me out of this..

Comment: I'm sorry but what is your problem actually? the link in comment is about sent push _from portal_ but your question is sent push _from app_.